# C# How to move change focus when press enter key in datagridview

Tags: c#

(I am sorry that I am not good at English.)

Hi, I want to move to fourth cell when pressed enter key in gridview.

And If focus is fourth cell, I want to move next row`s first cell.

Input data in gridview's first cell > Enter key > move to current row's fourth cell>
Enter key > move to next row`s first cell > ...

I tried this code.

```
private void ProductInfoView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                int irow = ProductInfoView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int icolumn = ProductInfoView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

                if (icolumn == ProductInfoView.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    ProductInfoView.CurrentCell = ProductInfoView[0, irow + 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    ProductInfoView.CurrentCell = ProductInfoView[icolumn + 3, irow];

                }
            }
        }
```

But **e.SuppressKeyPress = true;** wasn't worked.
When I pressed enter key, It goes next row's first cell.

So, I tried another code.

```
        private void ProductInfoView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                int irow = ProductInfoView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int icolumn = ProductInfoView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

                if (icolumn == ProductInfoView.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    ProductInfoView.CurrentCell = ProductInfoView[0, irow + 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    ProductInfoView.CurrentCell = ProductInfoView[icolumn + 3, irow];
                }
            }

        }
```

In this code, move to fourth cell was worked, but also enter key worked too.

Focus was move to next row`s fourth cell.

How can I fix it.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried to set e.Handled = true and e.SuppressKeyPress = true?

Comment: Yeah, I tried e.Handled = true and e.SuppressKeyPress = true but It does't worked....